# Messy semPaths printout - CFA

Tags: r, r-lavaan, semplot

Below is a path diagram for a CFA analysis I recently ran in RStudio. As you may note, the manifest nodes have random vertical black lines running through them. Further, it appears two values are being printed for the residual (i.e., overlaid values). This is causing the diagram to appear quite messy and unattractive.

Any idea on how to fix these issues? I've included the code that I ran for the path diagram using the `semPaths` command in the semPlot package.

[image: Image of path diagram]

```
semPaths(fit.BB7, intercepts = FALSE, residuals = TRUE, style="LISREL", layout="tree", rotation=1, optimizeLatRes = TRUE, whatLabels="std", sizeMan = 7, sizeLat = 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

The verticle bars are the thresholds. Simply set thresholds = F to turn it off, or ThreshAtSide = T to have them plotted at the side.